# cloud vision DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION response text Display in html using angular4

Tags: html, angular, geometry, google-cloud-vision

**I am using `cloud vision API` to extract text from the image,** in response, I am getting `vertices` and `text` but in HTML page how should I display text?

eg.

```
vertices : [[610,1637],[701,1637],[701,1654],[610,1654]]

text: "test"
```

I want to display above in HTML. I used `<ngvas-text>` but it's not working as I expected, the text should display as it is an image.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't provide much information about your issue. Could you please explain better what do you wish to achieve? What have you been doing up to now for trying to get the expected result?

Comment: Thanks, @RodrigoC. Actually, i Archived this with fabric js, I want itext like a feature of fabric js,

Comment: I apologize but I still don't understand what do you want to achieve. Could you please provide some more examples for this? Once I get a clearer picture of your issue, I will be able to help you further. Thanks.